# Count Like Dislike And Hits

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Hello i have 4 table like this.

[image]

how to sql sintax to get like that?

thanks before. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will list all records in `Computer` table whether it has a matching `id` or not on the other tables because `LEFT JOIN` was used. The reason for the separate calculation of number of hits of a computer is because it could yield invalid count if there are multiple matches of `Computer` into table `LIKE`.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, 
        SUM(sta_like = 1) total_like,
        SUM(sta_like = 0) total_dislike,
        COALESCE(totalHits, 0) total_hits
FROM    Computer a
        LEFT JOIN `LIKE` b
            ON a.id = b.id_com
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id_com_hits, COUNT(*) totalHits
            FROM    hits
            GROUP   BY id_com_hits
        ) c ON a.ID = c.id_com_hits
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41e48/2)